# How to Auto capture selfie when we smile in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to auto capture the selfie image when smile or movement detected through camera in flutter.
How can I achieve this, is there any tool or libraries?

Comment: This question is *waayy* to broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase ML do it and more

[FireBase ML](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces)

```
firebase_ml_custom: ^0.2.0+3
```